# GLSurfaceView OnToucListener only works when drawing

Tags: android, opengl-es, glsurfaceview

I'm using an `OnTouchListener` on a `GLSurfaceView`, but it appears that it only works while drawing.

So, if it takes too much time to draw the frame, I'll get most of the touch events handled, but if the frame is being drawn in less than 16ms, I've no chance to handle the events.

I'm using Android 4.3 to compile the app.

Comment: Why not use `onTouchEvent()` in the View?  e.g. https://code.google.com/p/android-breakout/source/browse/src/com/faddensoft/breakout/GameSurfaceView.java#74

Comment: It doesn't work with `onTouchEvent()` either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After closer analysis I noticed that the bug was in my code and has nothing to do with the question.